# JavaScript, MooTools - Class.Event - onComplete: Do nothing by default

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

I'd like to make it possible to use an onComplete event in my MooTools class by implementing `Events` and using `this.fireEvent("complete")`. By default I just want to let the class do nothing. So how would you realize the default "do nothing" thing the cleanest and safest way?

Should I just omit the option `onComplete` in the default class options object and still use `this.fireEvent("complete")` in the context? Or is this causing errors or something? I just did it that way all the time, but I'm not sure if this is the best way...

Would you use something like `if(this.options.onComplete && instanceOf(this.options.onComplete, Function)) { this.fireEvent("complete") }` instead? Or would you specify an empty function as default like `options: { onComplete: function(){} }`?

I don't care about the shortest code at this point but I was wondering how to do it the most conform and memory saving way.

Thanks for your recommendations! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.Event.js#L103) of MooTools:

```
if (!events || !events[type]) return this;
```

As you can see, the fireEvent will just return the current instance when an event is not found. Omitting `onComplete` and keeping `this.fireEvent('complete')` would therefore not give any errors or weird behaviour.

I would not even specify an empty function in the options. As you can see [here](https://github.com/darkwing/LightFace/blob/master/Source/LightFace.js#L41), the events are simply left undefined and only mentioned using a comment so people know they are present and can be used:

```
options: {
  //onComplete: $empty
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That's very nice. :)